# Can we open bim 360 autodesk sites in iframe

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-bim360

In my SPA app, can I open bim 360 docs urls in an iframe? I am getting "refused to connect" errors.

Any thoughts/ ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the content security policy, you cannot embed that in the iframe.

Instead, I would advise you to build your website integrating with Forge APIs.

- Tutorial: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels
- Samples:

  - https://github.com/autodesk-forge?q=bim360&type=all&language=&sort=
  - https://github.com/autodesk-forge?q=acc&type=all&language=&sort=